# How to draw a zero-length \psline without an arrow?

Tags: pstricks

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](5,5)
\psline[arrows=->](1,1)(1,1)
\psellipticarc[arrows=->](2.5,2.5)(1,2){0}{0}
\psellipticarcn[arrows=->](2.5,2.5)(2,1){0}{0}
\psarc[arrows=->](2.5,2.5){1}{0}{0}
\psarcn[arrows=->](2.5,2.5){2}{0}{0}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Question:

Should zero-length `\psline[arrows=->](1,1)(1,1)` be displayed?

Why does zero-length `\psellipticarc` get rendered while zero-length `\psarc` does not?

Comment: (1,1) to (1,1) is a rather short line? did you intend (0,0)(1,1) ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No, my intend is (1,1)(1,1). And I don't know (1,1) to (1,1) is a rather short line.

Comment: @chishimotoji that is specifying the start and end point to be at the same place what kind of line do you expect to see in that case? "short" was an under-statement, it has length 0pt.

Comment: @chishimotoji: You need to update your TeX installation. It seems HV has changed this behavior. Only `psline` still produces a single arrow that can be regarded as a feature.

Comment: The coordinates of `\psline[arrows=->](1,1)(1,1)`  are nonsense and if you want an arrow for such coordinates you get nonsense...

Comment: @Herbert: So `\psline[arrows=->](1,1)(1,1)` should be rendered as "nothing" or an arrow? The current condition in both PSTricks and TikZ, it produces an arrow that looks like a bug.

Comment: @Herbert And what's your idea about second question?

Comment: I do not get your output with an up-to-date PSTricks

Comment: With pstricks.tex from http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/texnik/tex/generic/pstricks/  you can use `\psLine` (uppercase L) which can have only _one_ or _two_ pairs of coordinates, but will test for a length between the points. Will later be on CTAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an up-to-date `pstricks.tex` from http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/texnik/tex/generic/pstricks/

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](5,5)
    \psLine[arrows=->](1,1)(1,1)
    \psellipticarc[arrows=->](2.5,2.5)(1,2){0}{0}
    \psellipticarcn[arrows=->](2.5,2.5)(2,1){0}{0}
    \psarc[arrows=->](2.5,2.5){1}{0}{0}
    \psarcn[arrows=->](2.5,2.5){2}{0}{0}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

you'll get an empty grid.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try out this:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](5,5)
\psline[arrows=->](1,1)(1,1)
\psline[arrows=->](0,1)(1,0)
\psellipticarc[arrows=->](2.5,2.5)(1,2){0}{360}
\psellipticarcn[arrows=->](2.5,2.5)(2,1){0}{360}
\psarc[arrows=->](2.5,2.5){1}{0}{360}
\psarcn[arrows=->](2.5,2.5){2}{0}{360}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

What do you want to get when letting start a vector (\psline) at the same point where it ends? Just produce an arrowhead with a given direction?

**Note:** `\psarc[arrows=->](2.5,2.5){1}{0}{360}`

The parentheses give the **coordinates of the center** of the arc of the circle.
The first mandatory argument gives the **radius** of the arc of the circle.
The second and third mandatory arguments give the **starting and ending angle** of the arc.

When both angles are chosen to 0, there is no arc to be drawn, as well as with the ellipses ... I cannot reproduce that the elliptic arcs are drawn.

```
\psellipticarc[arrows=->](2.5,2.5)(1,2){0}{0}
\psellipticarcn[arrows=->](2.5,2.5)(2,1){0}{0}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you are now using the latest update so you cannot reproduce the elliptical arcs.

Answer (score 1):

I can only reproduce the single arrow for `\psline[arrows=->](1,1)(1,1)` because I use the latest TeX Live 2018 update. I think someone has changed the arc-related macros several days ago.

A single arrow for the zero-length line is a feature that is intentionally kept as it is because according to someone it is useful for drawing zero-length vectors. TikZ also has the same feature, right? :-)

So if you want to get nothing for a zero-length line, do modify the `\psline` as follows.

```
\makeatletter
\def\psline{\pst@object{psline}}% a special Line 
\def\psline@i{\pst@getarrows{\begin@OpenObj \pst@getcoors[\psline@ii}}
\def\psline@ii{%
    \addto@pscode{
      \ifPst@noCurrentPoint\else\pst@cp\fi% current point?
      4 copy Pyth2 \psk@arrowlength ge 
        { \psline@iii \tx@Line }% arc and lineto type
        { pop pop pop pop } ifelse }%
  \end@OpenObj}
\makeatother
```

Here I present an example in which zero-length lines are practically useful in our life. Of course we can use conditional macro to get the same result.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\makeatletter
\def\psline{\pst@object{psline}}% a special Line 
\def\psline@i{\pst@getarrows{\begin@OpenObj \pst@getcoors[\psline@ii}}
\def\psline@ii{%
    \addto@pscode{
      \ifPst@noCurrentPoint\else\pst@cp\fi% current point?
      4 copy Pyth2 \psk@arrowlength ge 
        { \psline@iii \tx@Line }% arc and lineto type
        { pop pop pop pop } ifelse }%
  \end@OpenObj}
\makeatother

\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\newcommand\const[3][3]{%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\endcsname{round(#3:#1)}%
    \pstVerb{/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}%
}
\newcommand\Const[3][3]{\begingroup\edef\temp{\endgroup\noexpand\const[#1]{#2}{#3}}\temp}

\Const{Tpeak}{1}
\Const{Theta}{80/180*pi}
\Const{Gravity}{10}
\Const{SpeedFactor}{0.2}
\Const{FPS}{11}

\def\X#1{Vinit*cos(Theta)*#1}
\def\Y#1{Vinit*sin(Theta)*#1-Gravity*pow(2,#1)/2}

\Const{Vinit}{Tpeak*Gravity/sin(Theta)}
\Const{Xpeak}{\X{Tpeak}}
\Const{Ypeak}{\Y{Tpeak}}

\def\point#1{%
    \pnode(!Vinit Theta RadToDeg 2 copy cos mul #1 mul 3 1 roll sin mul #1 mul Gravity #1 2 exp mul 2 div sub){P}
    \pscircle[linecolor=red,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow](P){3pt}
    \pnode[!Vinit Theta RadToDeg cos mul SpeedFactor mul 0](P){PX}
    \pnode[!0 Vinit Theta RadToDeg sin mul Gravity #1 mul sub SpeedFactor mul](P){PY}
    %
    \psline[linecolor=blue]{->}(P)(PX)
    \psline[linecolor=magenta]{->}(P)(PX|PY)
    \psline[linecolor=blue]{->}(P)(PY)
}


\Const{DeltaTime}{1/\FPS}
\Const[0]{TotalFrames}{\FPS*2*Tpeak}
\Const[0]{TotalFrames}{TotalFrames+1}

\begin{document}
\multido{\nt=0.000+\DeltaTime}{\TotalFrames}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](0,-35pt)(2\dimexpr\Xpeak\psxunit\relax,\dimexpr\Ypeak\psyunit+7pt\relax)
    \parabola[linewidth=0.5\pslinewidth,linestyle=dashed](0,0)(\Xpeak,\Ypeak)
    \point{\nt}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]